# Extract params from multipart/form-data body WSO2

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm deploing as prototype API with POST method with content-type of multipart/form-data. There is two fields: photo and reqId. How can I extract reqId from request using inline implementation? `mc.getPayloadJSON()` returns `null`.
Here's a SWAGGER of that part in service:

```
/checkPhoto:
post:
  summary: "Check photo"
  consumes:
  - "multipart/form-data"
  produces: 
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - in: "formData"
    name: "photo"
    type: "file"
    required: true
    description: "Photo"
  - in: "formData"
    name: "reqId"
    type: "string"
    required: true
    description: "Unique id"
  responses:
    400:
      description: "Invalid input"
    200:
      description: "Success"
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ApiResponse"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<property name="reqId" expression="//reqId/text()" />
```